# using index value greater than as a condition for np where

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to look for true conditions where "this" is greater than "that" starting with row 2 (index is greater than 1).
For instance if the df is 5 rows long and "this" is greater than "that" in rows 1, 4, and 5 then the return would be 0,0,0,1,1.
The index itself is a datetime string.  However, someinteger is the actual index row value (a value from zero to length-1 of the df)
It seems pretty easy and trivial but I'm having difficulty. I have tried this, but it's not working.

```
import panda as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'this': [5,2,2,5,5], 
    'that': [3,3,3,3,3]},
    index=['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-05'])

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

someintegervalue = 1

df['blah blah blah'] = np.where(df.index > someintegervalue & df['this'] > df['that'], 0, 1)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example dataframe as DataFrame constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. You just need to enclose your conditions in () and flip the last two np.where() arguments.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'this': [5,2,2,5,5], 
    'that': [3,3,3,3,3]},
    index=['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-05'])

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df['blah blah blah']= np.where((df.index > df.index[1]) & (df['this'] > df['that']), 1, 0)
```

Alternatively, you could use this if you wanted to input a date instead of an index position.

```
from pandas import Timestamp
df['blah blah blah']= np.where((df.index > Timestamp('2022-01-02')) & (df['this'] > df['that']), 1, 0)
```

Output:

```
               this   that     blah blah blah
2022-01-01     5       3       0
2022-01-02     2       3       0
2022-01-03     2       3       0
2022-01-04     5       3       1
2022-01-05     5       3       1
```

Comment: Your code works fine.  It was basically what I was trying before I posted here, but I got the error message:  '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'.  After seeing your code works,  I figured out it's because I'm using a numeric index value and my actual index is a date string.  I  substituted someintegervalue with df.index[someintegervalue] and it works.  Thanks!

Comment: I updated my code and your op with a datetime index.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you could just do:

```
import numpy as np
df['blah blah blah']= np.where((np.arange(len(df)) > someintegervalue) & (df['this']>df['that']), 0, 1)
```

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. It throws `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` with both an integer index as described in the original post and a datetime index as mentioned in comments. Additionally, the 0 and 1 for the last two arguments in np.where() are flipped and the output is backwards compared to the desired output of `[0,0,0,1,1]` for `df['blah blah blah']`.

Comment: I hadn't seen the comment. It was missing parentheses ;)